# How to show Server down or Unavailable alert in jaxrs

Tags: jax-rs

I am working with Jaxrs restful webservice.Can anybody give me an idea how to implement service unavailable alert.particularly when server is down.

Thanks,
Prabhash

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting your server on the Google Cloud Platform, I would suggest Google Stackdriver https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/

It can monitor your instances and give you warnings by email or SMS.

I assume there are similar services for other IaaS.